# References for a Shloka on speech

Tags: history, shloka

I was looking for various prescriptive Shlokas on the speech of a person. Came across this one with no references mentioned:

> प्रियवाक्य प्रदानेन सर्वे तुष्यन्ति जन्तवः
>
> तस्मात् तथैव कर्तव्यं वचने का दरिद्रता

Does anyone know, which text can this can be traced back to?

Comment: Please consider adding translations to all the questions in which you have put down verses in Devanagiri. Let us not make this site exclusive to Indians :).

Comment: Amit. you can accept the answer if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> प्रियवाक्यप्रदानेन सर्वे तुष्यन्ति जन्तवः। 
>   तस्मात्तदेव वक्तव्यं
>   वचने का दरिद्रता ॥
>
> Speaking pleasing words satisfies all living entities. Therefore, only
>   pleasing words should be spoken. What poverty exists in speech?
>
> – Subhashita Manjari – 14.288

Reference: [Immortal Sayings By B. R Suhas](https://books.google.com/books?id=NItihbSm3poC&lpg=PP1&dq=editions%3AjAS4P62aMCMC&pg=PA78#v=onepage&q=speaking%20pleasing%20words&f=false)

P.S. I don't think your question is valid for this site though because [Subhashita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subhashita) is Sanskrit literature but not necessarily Hindu literature.

Comment: Well, I assumed it might originate in hindu literature. Should I delete this question? And, thanks for the answer :)